# How to reserve current IP address for existing azure service fabric cluster so that I can destroy the cluster and recreate it with same IP address?

Tags: ip, azure-service-fabric

1. I already created a service fabric cluster in a resource group in my subscription.
2. I would like to reserve currently assigned public IP address for this cluster.
3. I would like to delete and recreate my resource group as many times as I want.
4. I know that when I delete resource group, all resources in that group (including service fabric cluster) will be destroyed.
5. But I want to keep the same IP address so that I can assign this address to newly created service fabric cluster in the new resource group.
6. At any given time, there is only 1 resource group with only 1 service fabric cluster in it in my subscription.

What is the best and the most effective way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using an ARM template to create your cluster then what you need to do is move the creation of the public IP address out of that ARM template and out of the clusters resource group. You're basically saying you want that public IP permanently, thus you need to put it in a resource group that you will keep long term.

Then in the ARM template for your SF Cluster you can reference that public IP rather than creating a new one each time.

Comment: But first how do I reserve the ip address that is already on the cluster?

Comment: For that I would try to move the PublicIP resource you have out of the resource group. There are powershell commands for moving resources, but not all resources are currently supported. I'm unsure about public ip's. If you can't move it then you're kinda stuck and might have to take a hit and lose that IP once and claim a new one that you can keep permanently. Or alternatively you could manually delete everything in that resource group except the public ip. Then create new clusters in a different resource group.

Comment: Lets see if others have a way to do this.